# Activerecord callback, previous_changes vs. changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, callback

I'm trying to understand what the difference between these two methods is. Here is the documentation for each:

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveModel/Dirty/previous_changes

https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveModel/Dirty/changes

It appears to me after reading this documentation that `previous_changes` is what was changed after the changes are done, meaning in an `after_*` filter, while `changes` is what will be changed, meaning it's useful in a `before_*` filter.

Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: I wonder why it's called `previous`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

yes you understood it rightly

These are dirty object methods

`changes` is used to know the changes that would take place if you try to save an object
`previous_changes` is used to know the changes that reflected by saving an object.

But if you try to reload the object both `changes` and `previous_changes` would return empty hash {} as new copy of the record is being fetched from Database

Eg User(id: 1, name: 'Nimish', age: 24, email: 'test@example.com')

```
user = User.find(1)
user.changes #Will output => {}
user.previous_changes #Will output => {}
user.name = 'Test User'
user.changes #Will output => {name: ['Nimish', 'Test User']}
user.previous_changes #Will output => {}
user.save
user.changes #Will output => {}
user.previous_changes #Will output => {name: ['Nimish', 'Test User']}
user.reload
user.changes #Will output => {}
user.previous_changes #Will output => {}
```

## Note

You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53388741/7006199) for more help.