# Rails model callback (after create/update) attribute_was not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, attributes

I am migrating a rails 5.1 app to rails 5.2.1. In my models I am using callbacks to create an activity log after a model was created or updated. Unfortunately `todo.name` and `todo.name_was` is always the same - the current value. This applies to every attribute and every model. Also `changed?` returns false.

Am I missing something?

I appreciate your help a lot!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You won't get `attribute_was` in after_create/update callback as the records has been changed in DB at this point.

You can make use of `previous_changes` in `after_create/update` callbacks.

Here is an example below.

Consider, User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  before_update :check_for_changes
  after_update :check_for_previous_changes

  private def check_for_changes
    puts changes # => {"name"=>["Nimish Gupta", "Nimish Mahajan"], "updated_at"=>[Tue, 20 Nov 2018 00:02:14 PST -08:00, Tue, 20 Nov 2018 00:06:15 PST -08:00]}
    puts previous_changes # => {} At this point this will be empty beacuse changes are not made to DB yet
    puts name_was # => "Nimish Gupta" i.e the original name
    puts name # => "Nimish Mahajan" i.e the new name which will be going to save in DB
  end

  private def check_for_previous_changes
    puts changes # => {}
    # Please note `changes` would be empty now because record have been saved in DB now

    # but you can make use of previous_changes method to know what change has occurred.
    puts previous_changes # => {"name"=>["Nimish Gupta", "Nimish Mahajan"], "updated_at"=>[Tue, 20 Nov 2018 00:06:15 PST -08:00, Tue, 20 Nov 2018 00:08:07 PST -08:00]}

    puts name_was # => "Nimish Mahajan" i.e the new name which have been saved in DB
    puts name # => "Nimish Mahajan" i.e the new name which have been saved in DB

    # to get the previous name if after_create/update callback, Please use.
    puts previous_changes[:name][0]
  end

end

u = User.first # => #<User id: 1, name: "Nimish Gupta">
u.update(name: 'Nimish Mahajan') # => this will fire both before_update and after_update callbacks.
```

Hope this will help you.

You can also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016584/activerecord-callback-previous-changes-vs-changes/45017487#45017487) answer for more information

Comment: Thannk you very much! It's strange tho how it worked in 5.1. 

Comment: Is there any workaround for detecting changes within the hash of an attribute? I have a table that is accessed by `A.B `and this gives certain attributes like c,d,e,f. I am making changes to `f` atrribute which is an hash. Something like this: ```{:e=> 'hello', :f=> {"new_field"=>"In progress"}}```  So when I make changes to new_field it's not reflecting in previous_changes method or changes method in after_update callback.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using `changed?` on a persisted objet, `attribute_was`, `changed?` only works when object is dirty see for more details  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord 
end
todo = Todo.new
todo.changed? # => false
todo.persisted? # => false
```

If you save the object in DB the object becomes persisted(no more dirty data present)

```
todo = Todo.new(name: 'Test') 
todo.name_was # => nil
todo.name_changed? #=> true
todo.save
todo.persisted? # => true
todo.name_was # => Test
todo.name_changed? #=> false
```